# Node.js Shell Script And Arguments

Tags: bash, node.js

I need to execute a bash script in node.js. Basically, the script will create user account on the system. I came across [this example](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/nodejs-cloud-server-in-three-minutes) which gives me an idea how to go about it. However, the script itself needs arguments like the username, the password and the real name of the user. I still can't figure out how to pass those arguments to the script doing something like this:

```
var commands = data.toString().split('\n').join(' && ');
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can pass those arguments and execute the bash script within node.js over an ssh connection.
thanks

Answer (score 68):

See the documentation [here](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.6/api/child_processes.html#child_process.spawn).  It is very specific on how to pass command line arguments.  Note that you can use `exec` or `spawn`.  `spawn` has a specific argument for command line arguments, while with `exec` you would just pass the arguments as part of the command string to execute.

Directly from the documentation, with explanation comments inline

```
var util  = require('util'),
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    ls    = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']); // the second arg is the command 
                                          // options

ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {    // register one or more handlers
  console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

ls.on('exit', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

Whereas with exec

```
var util = require('util'),
    exec = require('child_process').exec,
    child;

child = exec('cat *.js bad_file | wc -l', // command line argument directly in string
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {      // one easy function to capture data/errors
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

Finally, note that exec buffers the output.  If you want to stream output back to a client, you should use `spawn`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. What I meant actually is that the command itself is in a bash script which requires arguments. And I don't know how to pass these arguments with node.js while reading the content of the bash file.

Comment: @joque i don't know what you mean.  If you were invoking the script on the CLI, you would do `command arg1 arg2...` you can do that with node, as shown in the examples.

Comment: well @hvgotcodes, I would like to follow the procedure in [http://blog.nodejitsu.com/nodejs-cloud-server-in-three-minutes] and execute the script **passing arguments**. Right now, I don't know how to do it, unless I break it down command after command. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: I'm just curious, why do you require `util`?

Comment: @hvgotcodes how can i use spawn for 'sudo hcitool lescan --duplicates &'

Answer (score 11):

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var child = exec('cat *.js | wc -l', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
  if (error) console.log(error);
  process.stdout.write(stdout);
  process.stderr.write(stderr);
});
```

This way is nicer because console.log will print blank lines.

Comment: see this answer to promisify `exec`  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56095793/753279

Answer (score 10):

You can use `process.argv`. It's an array containing the command line arguments. The first element will be `node` the second element will be the name of the JavaScript file. All next elements will be any additional command line you given.

You can use it like:

```
var username = process.argv[2];
var password = process.argv[3];
var realname = process.argv[4];
```

Or iterate over the array. Look at the example: http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#process.argv