# Is it possible to get the output of a bash shell command as a string in node.js?

Tags: bash, node.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Node.js Shell Script And Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464036/node-js-shell-script-and-arguments)

I'd like to get the output of a shell command as a string in node.js, but I'm not exactly sure where to start.  An example of such a command is the bash command "ls", which lists the contents of the current folder, and prints the results in the terminal window. Is it possible to convert this output to a Javascript string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the documentation for "[Child Processes](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)" in the nodejs.org API documentation which provides example code to handle the exact task you mention, i.e. running the 'ls' command and capturing its output.

```
var spawn=require('child_process').spawn,
    ls=spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']); // runs the 'ls -lh /usr' shell cmd

ls.stdout.on('data', function(data) { // handler for output on STDOUT
  console.log('stdout: '+data);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', function(data) { // handler for output on STDERR
  console.log('stderr: '+data);
});

ls.on('exit', function(code) { // handler invoked when cmd completes
  console.log('child process exited with code '+code);
});
```