# Routing table in javascript

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Is there any way to read a routing table in `javascript`? 
Using `webrtc` I can retrieve local **IP**s, but what with routing table? Is there something that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't retrieve the routing table in a web browser (even with WebRTC).

However, in NodeJs (still JS), you can for instance execute some shell code ( `netstat -rn` ) like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464036/node-js-shell-script-and-arguments).